# CMake custom target for latex document only runs when ALL is specified

Tags: cmake, latex

I am trying to add documentation to the build process of a CMake project, a lot like in [this chapter](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Custom%20Commands.html) from CMake's own "Mastering CMake." Here is the excerpt:

```cmake
# Add the rule to build the .pdf file from the .tex
# file. This relies on LATEX and DVIPDF being set correctly
#
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${LATEX}  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${DVIPDF} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.dvi
  )

# finally add the custom target that when invoked
# will cause the generation of the pdf file

add_custom_target(TDocument ALL
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  )
```

The behavior of this bit of CMake, in alignment with the documentation for `add_custom_target`, compiles my latex document every time I build my project. I want the latex document to be built only when it's dependencies are altered. So, I modified it to be

```cmake
# Add the rule to build the .pdf file from the .tex
# file. This relies on LATEX and DVIPDF being set correctly
#
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${LATEX}  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${DVIPDF} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.dvi
  )

# finally add the custom target that when invoked
# will cause the generation of the pdf file

add_custom_target(TDocument # no longer specifying ALL
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  )
```

I thought this would be as simple as removing `ALL` from the custom target, but instead of building the PDF whenever its dependencies are altered, it is not built at all, whether `doc1.tex` is edited or even if `doc1.pdf` is deleted.

I have used this pattern successfully to manage, for example, CSV files that are created by C++ executables before so it's not at all clear to me why it wouldn't work with latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the CMake documentation for [`add_custom_target()`][1] (emphasis theirs)

> Adds a target with the given name that executes the given commands. The target has no output file and is ***always considered out of date*** even if the commands try to create a file with the name of the target. Use the [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html) command to generate a file with dependencies.

Since the target is always out-of-date it will always build, regardless of its status. If you want a target with dependencies on source files and/or output use [`add_custom_command()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html).

After re-reading your question and code more carefully, your `CMakeLists.txt` is correct.

```console
$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  doc1.tex

$ cat CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(q)

set(LATEX "latex")
set(DVIPDF "dvipdf")

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT  ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${LATEX}  ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/doc1.tex
  COMMAND ${DVIPDF} ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.dvi
  )

add_custom_target(TDocument ALL
  DEPENDS ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/doc1.pdf
  )

$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nega/q

$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/nega/q -B/home/nega/q --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles /home/nega/q//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
make  -f CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
cd /home/nega/q && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
make  -f CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
[100%] Generating doc1.pdf
latex /home/nega/q/doc1.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/nega/q/doc1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
No file doc1.aux.
[1] (./doc1.aux) )
Output written on doc1.dvi (1 page, 1760 bytes).
Transcript written on doc1.log.
dvipdf /home/nega/q/doc1.dvi
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
[100%] Built target TDocument
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles 0

$ make VERBOSE=1
/usr/bin/cmake -S/home/nega/q -B/home/nega/q --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles /home/nega/q//CMakeFiles/progress.marks
make  -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
make  -f CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/depend
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
cd /home/nega/q && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
make  -f CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/nega/q'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'CMakeFiles/TDocument.dir/build'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
[100%] Built target TDocument
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/nega/q'
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /home/nega/q/CMakeFiles 0

$ touch doc1.tex

$ make
[100%] Generating doc1.pdf
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2022/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/nega/q/doc1.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def)
(./doc1.aux) [1] (./doc1.aux) )
Output written on doc1.dvi (1 page, 1760 bytes).
Transcript written on doc1.log.
[100%] Built target TDocument

$
```

You'll notice that with the second invocation of `make VERBOSE=1` that `latex` and `dvipdf` are not run, since `doc1.tex` hasn't changed. After `touch`ing `doc1.tex` changing its timestamp, and running `make` for the third time, `latex` and `dvipdf` are run again.

If your `doc1.tex` is being processed every time you build, I suspect either something in your greater build process is touching your source file (`doc1.tex`), changing its timestamp, or your source file has a "future date". A future date for a timestamp will cause the source file to be out-of-date until that time has passed.

Comment: I thought a command needed a target. If this isn't true, how does CMake know when to run the latex commands?

Comment: i updated my answer. apologies, i read your code too quickly earlier.

Comment: I might have been a bit unclear too-- your example still specifies `ALL` in `add_custom_target()`, which works as expected for me. I'm trying to have the latex commands run only when the dependencies change (ie. I edit `doc1.tex`), as opposed to running every time I build. I've added another snippet to my question.

Comment: Yes, in your first example, things _should_ work as you expect. That is, latex/dvipdf only run when `doc1.tex` changes. If it doesn't, there's problem not related to that bit of your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: I created a fresh project and it does not have this issue- thank you for pointing it out, when I find out what is causing this I will report it here for future reference.

Comment: The problem was that instead of prepending the cmake dirs to filenames in the custom command, I used `WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. Upon closer reading of the documentation, that only helps cmake execute the command, not find the relevant files to check if they're up to date.